# How do I deploy to a remote docker host on windows server 2016?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-machine, windows-server-2016

So I have 2016 vm set up on azure and I'd like deploy a container to it. Most articles I've read recommend using docker compose and machine to set this up, but I can't find any examples on how to do it for server 2016. I realize it's brand new.

My first pass was to attempt to add it as an existing host to docker machine, but I can't figure that out. I found an example, but it only goes through docker machine actually creating a new host on azure, which isn't gonna work when I need to setup another workstation to do work with it. Looking at the windows docker cli docs, I don't see any flags to set the remote host.

So, given a server 2016 server running the docker engine (windows containers), how do I build my application into an image locally and deploy it to the remote server?

Has anyone figure this out yet?

Comment: well, just specify remote host address as a docker host in the settings.conf or whatever its called?

Answer (score 0):

the common way to develop and deploy an application with docker would be to build the container image on your dev machine, push the image to your docker repository (either docker hub or a private registry) and then docker run the image on your server, which will implicitly pull that image from your hub.
To run the docker commands on your server, you can either remote through powershell or setup your docker service to listen remotely. Within an azure subnet this could be done unsecured, but you will very probably make it save by [protecting a Windows 2016 Docker engine with TLS](https://stefanscherer.github.io/protecting-a-windows-2016-docker-engine-with-tls/)

Comment: "To run the docker commands on your server, you can either remote through powershell or setup your docker service to listen remotely. " This doesn't appear to be an option in 2016 (?). So this all seem very manual. How would this work with CI, for example. I've seen several examples where you tell docker to pull a repo and build that into a base image. How would I even send that command to the server? It sounds like remote commands are the way to go, but I'm not seeing how to actually do it.

Comment: If you mean "manual" like "without GUI", you are correct. A very common way to make Ci/CD work is with TFS/VSTS and it's agents. you can integrate docker commands in these tasks to run remotely on your server. this link may help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/08/19/build-push-and-run-docker-images-with-visual-studio-team-services/

Comment: I meant "manual" as in, I have to control too much about the process including being on docker host machine. We use git with appveyor as our ci solution. If I knew how to even send a command to the docker host so that it could run the build scripts, it would be progress.